# bash script to filter hostname names from a YAML file which meet required condition

Tags: bash, scripting

I have the below `file.txt` which is created by an upstream process:

```
Host1:
    True
Host2:
    'test.ping' is not available.
Host4:
    Failed due to space.
Host6:
    True
```

Using bash script how, can I filter all the host names which **don't** have **True** in the second line. Please note, as its a YAML file the values in the second line has 3 tabs/ 3spaces in between.

Desired output file:

```
Host2
Host4
```

Comment: The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: Sure Cyrus. I tried my bit but forgot to add it. I have added it now in the comment section. Hope someone could help.

Answer (score 0):

Using an array and regex with bash4+.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

mapfile -t array < file.txt

for n in "${!array[@]}"; do
  if [[ ${array[n]} == Host* && ! ${array[n+1]} =~ ^[[:blank:]]+True$ ]]; then
    echo "${array[n]%:}"
  fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks Jetchisel. I need a one line command as i need to pass it through a Jenkins pipeline using sshCommand remote. Something in line of :  awk '!/True/ { print x }; { x=$0 }' file.txt.  Just want to return the host name.